# (Monte Media Library) Record screen im mp4 format

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Below is Monte Media Library. 
http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/

I am using MonteScreenRecorder jar for record screen.

I am able to store video file in avi format but i want to store in mp4 format

Here is code for avi

```
import java.awt.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.monte.media.Format;
import org.monte.media.math.Rational;
import org.monte.screenrecorder.ScreenRecorder;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.*;

...
private ScreenRecorder screenRecorder;

public void startRecording() throws Exception
{
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
        .getDefaultScreenDevice()
        .getDefaultConfiguration();

    this.screenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(gc,
        new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
        new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
            CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
            DepthKey, 24, FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(15),
            QualityKey, 1.0f,
            KeyFrameIntervalKey, 15 * 60),
        new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black",
            FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)),
        null);

    this.screenRecorder.start();
}

public void stopRecording() throws Exception
{
    this.screenRecorder.stop();
}
...
```

What are the change is required let me know.

Please Help

Thank you

Comment: by chance did you get a chance to improve the quality of the video? What parameters needs to be changed in the above code?

Comment: i did not research about video quality.

Comment: I have also used this code to generate avi files. However, none of my avi files actually run. while i am playing avi, it displays black screen only. Have you any idea, if i am missing anything?